# My recommender does not personally know any of the faculty members at the PhD programs I'm applying. Is this bad?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, recommendation-letter

Basically, will my recommenders not being known to the faculty of my targetted PhD programs hurt my chances of admission? I am an undergraduate student, looking for PhD programs in CS.

Answer (score 1):

Given that this is the most common situation, it is unlikely that it is a negative. In fact, since US doctoral admissions in US are normally by committee it might not make a lot of difference even if they do know someone. Admissions isn't based on personal contacts but on the record of the candidate and a judgement of the likelihood of their success.

Members of a committee can, of course, look for information about letter writers online, but, given the scale of things, that isn't a universal practice. The reputation of the college you apply from will normally be trusted to extend to its faculty.

So, no, it won't hurt your chances. Hopefully the content of their letter predicts your success in grad study and beyond. That is the more important thing (along with all of the other indicators).

---

There are exceptions to the above, especially for a positive effect when someone is known.